# How to enable "Caret Browsing" functionality in WebBrowser control in C# or VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have IE 8 installed on my machine; and trying to integrate the "Caret Browsing" (navigation using Keyboard) concept into application which i am planning to develop.

My sample application in VB.NET as follows:

1. A Form - Form1
2. A Text box - TextBox1
3. A Button - Button1
4. A WebBrowser control - WebBrowser1

Added following line of code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text.Trim())
End Sub
```

While running the application; if I click on F7 I am not seeing the message box of IE saying that "Are you want to enable Caret Browsing feature"?

Where as I was getting the same confirmation, if I click the same in IE 8 browser...

Does WebBrowser control have any limitations?

Any Work around to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it wouldn't take to long to implement a system yourself.

Use the forms property "KeyPreview" to allow your form to capture key presses no matter what is focused.  Then edit/run stuff on the pages yourself through webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("elementid) or something similar.  You can simulate button presses and edit a wide range of controls in a webbrowser via this method.

Hope that helps.

Remember, if you find and answer that works, please click the "check" located on the left of the answer.  This will give your profile a higher rating and a better chance of getting answers next time.